# Catch "PDOException" with custom exception handler

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I have a simple piece of code, using PDO in PHP:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDatabase', $username, $password, 
        array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    ));
```

and this custom exception handler:

```
function my_exceptionHandler($exception) {
    echo "Exception: {$exception->getMessage()}";
}
set_exception_handler("my_exceptionHandler");
```

Although the custom exception handler catches all the other exceptions, but it fails to catch the PDO-exceptions i.e. when the username and password for database are incorrect, and I just get the plain error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is there anything I miss like a overloading custom exception handler function for this type of exceptions?
**And note that when I wrapped the PDO code in try and catch block, it worked fine but I want to catch it in my custom exception handler.**

Comment: I think it's because PDO uses its own Exception handle class.

Comment: @hjpotter92 : so how can I catch the PDOexcepion with a custom exception handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If it's **full and complete** error message you have - then there is some your own code ( most likely a global try..catch) that prints the caught error out.
(If not - please, ask question properly, providing full and complete error message - so, we'll be able to help you out.)

Comment: It was surrounded by another global try catch which I was forgot.